# pandas Date get numeric Time intervall

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following dataframe example with the Date and Interval:

```
       Date     Interval        
0   2013-08-01  14:00:00                
1   2013-08-01  14:15:00                
2   2013-08-01  14:30:00                
3   2013-08-01  14:45:00        
4   2013-08-01  15:00:00
        ...
```

What i want is a new Column where the Interval is mapped like:

```
00:00:00 = 1            
00:15:00 = 2                
00:30:00 = 3        
00:45:00 = 4
    ...
23:45:00 = 96
```

So every 15Minutes is 1 Intervall.
The rows in the dataframe are mixed, so i cant start a counter and increase the value. i need to use the time value in the Interval Column to get the mapped value in the new Column

i tried:

```
dates = pandas.to_datetime(df['Interval'])
df['IntervalMapped']= dates.dt.hour * 2 + dates.dt.minute//15 + 1
```

but thats wrong

Comment: i did not unterstand that, could you explain it in a clear way? @ScottBoston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, I think you want this:

```
 df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Interval'])
 df['IntervalMap'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour.mul(4) + df['timestamp'].dt.minute.floordiv(15) + 1
```

Output:

```
         Date  Interval           timestamp  IntervalMap
0  2013-08-01  14:00:00 2013-08-01 14:00:00           57
1  2013-08-01  14:15:00 2013-08-01 14:15:00           58
2  2013-08-01  14:30:00 2013-08-01 14:30:00           59
3  2013-08-01  14:45:00 2013-08-01 14:45:00           60
4  2013-08-01  15:00:00 2013-08-01 15:00:00           61
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a series with minimum and maximum dates+interval and map that to the datetime column

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Interval'])

rng = pd.date_range(df['datetime'].min(), df['datetime'].max(), freq = '15T')
s = pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(rng)+1, 1), index = rng)

df['IntervalMapped'] = df['datetime'].map(s)
df.drop('datetime', axis = 1, inplace = True)

    Date        Interval    IntervalMapped
0   2013-08-01  14:00:00    1
1   2013-08-01  14:15:00    2
2   2013-08-01  14:30:00    3
3   2013-08-01  14:45:00    4
4   2013-08-01  15:00:00    5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but thats not correct. 14:00:00 is not 1. 00:00:00 is 1...00:15:00 is 2.... and so on

Comment: @Bonjas, Got it. What happens if the date goes in to the next date? Are uou only considering the interval column?

Comment: @Vaishali Yes just the interval. The Interval is already combined like Scott Boston Solution

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might want to treat the "hms" form as text and write your own counting function? Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def converter(hms):
    """Takes a time in hms returns number of 15 second intervals after 00:00:00.
    """
    h,m,s = hms.split(':')
    return int(h)*4+int(m)//15


converter('02:15:00')  # 9

path = 'YOUR path'
new_df = pd.read_csv(path+'stack.txt')

new_df['Interval Mapped'] = new_df['Interval'].apply(lambda x: converter(x))
new_df
```